# How do I deploy database with my project?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2008, deployment, windows-mobile

I have a Windows mobile project an have added a small sqlite database to it.
I have set the "Copy to Output Directory" on the db file to "Copy Always".
But how do I get the database to be deployed with the project?

Comment: Depends on how exactly do you do deployment. What's your deployment model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean "how do I get Visual Studio to deploy the file when I hit F5" then you need to set the "Build Action" to "Content".  If you mean "How do I deploy the database to end users along with my application" then the answer is that you need to include the database file in your application deployment CAB.

Comment: Thanks, haven't tested yet. but it was excacly what I wanted. =)